# How to programmatically detect debug mode in nodejs?

Tags: debugging, node.js

I've seen this question asked of other platform/languages - any ideas? I'd like to do something like:

```
if (detectDebug())
{
    require('tty').setRawMode(true);    
    var stdin = process.openStdin();

    stdin.on('keypress', function (chunk, key) {
        DoWork();
    }
}
else
{
    DoWork();
}
```

I'd like to be able to toggle keyboard input as a start for the script when debugging so that I can have a moment to fire up chrome to listen to my node-inspector port.

***Quick update - I'm guessing I can actually use "process.argv" to detect if --debug was passed in. Is this the best/right way?

Comment: The "process.argv" does not help you when you call: node debug script.js. Also when you use --debug, the execution does not stop at "debugger" instructions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

NodeJS creates a `v8debug` global object when running in debug mode: `node debug script.js`

So, a possible solution would be:

```
var debug = typeof v8debug === 'object';
```

For my use case, I use it because I want to avoid passing environment variables. My main node process starts child node processes and I want a `node debug mainScript.js` to trigger debug mode for children as well (again, without passing env variables to child processes)

Comment: thanks, this also better answers the question (which is not "how can i set production mode")

Comment: Per @Alex it appears the global does not exist in newer versions of Node, including the latest LTS.

Comment: This has not been working since several major Node versions ago.

Answer (score 32):

I use this

```
var debug = typeof v8debug === 'object' 
            || /--debug|--inspect/.test(process.execArgv.join(' '));
```

which supports, `--debug`, `--debug-brk`, `--inspect` and `--inspect=1234`

Comment: Good answer. When testing my vscode extension v8debug is not present, so the top answer would not work for me.  But --debug-brk is there so your code caught it :)

Comment: This worked when I changed `process.execArgv` to `process.argv` when debugging using VS Code.

Comment: for those using TypeScript, remember to prepend v8debug with global.v8debug. Please keep in mind that newer versions of NodeJS do not even set v8debug, so that's why this answer that I'm commenting on is the best since it catches more modern versions of NodeJS.

Comment: This doesn't work generally since a debugger can be attached after the process has started

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well true, but you can create function that checks it on runtime, when needed, `isDebug = () => typeof v8debug === 'object' 
            || /--debug|--inspect/.test(process.execArgv.join(' '));`

Comment: That won't work command line flags don't magically appear when you trigger the debugger with a signal or API call

Comment: oh right, do you have anything else in mind then @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: @bentael yes - we are discussing this internally in core: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9617#issuecomment-521955240

Answer (score 32):

The global `v8debug` variable mentioned in the other answers seem to be removed in Node v7.0.0 (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9617). Also, checking process arguments (i.e. `process.execArgv`) seem to be unreliable since Node can enter debug mode at runtime. VS Code, for example, doesn't always starts Node with the `--inspect` option even when debugging. (depend on your debug config)

The most reliable solution I could find is to use `inspector.url()` to check if Node is listening for debug connections.

```js
const inspector = require('inspector');

function isInDebugMode() {
    return inspector.url() !== undefined;
}
```

I have tested this method with Node versions `v12.22.1`, `v14.16.1`, and `v16.1.0` and it worked for all of them.

Answer (score 27):

There is a node.js native support that using `inspector.url()` to check if there is active inspector, it just shows if process is debug mode or not currently. See [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#inspector_inspector_url) for more.

Comment: Finally an actual answer :)

Comment: my compiler says "cannot find name: inspector"

Comment: Hi, @birgersp if you can't find inspector you can try 'const inspector = require('inspector')', which you can see the details of office doc https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html

Answer (score 10):

I think there's a bunch of confusion in this question.

Based on your question, I think what you really want is the `node --debug-brk` command line flag. That will have node start v8 with a debugger running and automatically stop on a breakpoint before the first line of your `.js` program. You don't need to reinvent this. I use this for debugging mocha tests, express.js startup issues, etc. This will eliminate your need to detect this manually.

Secondly, `NODE_ENV=production` is nothing more than a convention that many programs use to indicate "you are running in production" and therefore certain things like really sending emails, using the real payment gateway, etc should be enabled. However what environment you are in when `NODE_ENV` is NOT production (or is unset) should definitely NOT be assumed to be debugging. The most sane assumption there is that the environment is a development environment, but even then this whole convention is pretty brittle in my opinion.

Thirdly, just FYI check out [tty.isatty()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_tty_isatty_fd) which will accurately tell you if your program is being run on an interactive terminal (like from a command shell). This will be `false` when your program is being run by a process supervisor provided by your OS (upstart, sysvinit, etc). This check is commonly use to toggle command line programs between interactive and scripted modes. It's not entirely perfect or infallible, but it is widely adopted in the posix world.

Fourth, from some quick experimentation, the `v8debug` global @Gabriel Petrovay indicates seems to **only be set when doing `node debug script.js` and not set when doing `node --debug script.js`.** Not sure why that is. If such a thing was reliable, that would seem like the most correct approach to finding out "is this v8 instance in debug mode".

Answer (score 6):

```
var detectDebug = function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
};
```

to run in debug mode:

```
$ node app.js
```

to run in production mode:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

Some frameworks recognize the production mode this way. See [express.js doc](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration).

Comment: This seems to work with electron apps, but the values are not intuitive.  When running with npm start process.env.NODE_ENV is 'production' but when the app is packaged into a stand-alone executable the variable is undefined.

Comment: This is brittle and inconsistent. There's far better ways to do this in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

The global.v8debug object only seems to be created / exposed when the debug or --debug-brk command line option is set. It's strange and annoying it's not created when --debug is set.

A hacky way to do this would be to look at the process.execArgv array (not process.argv) for --debug, --debug-brk or debug.

Comment: you would think... but the --debug command line flag is consumed before it gets to us

Comment: seems to be available in process.execArgv instead

Comment: I think that with `--debug` its only listening for a debugger to attach. With the other cases the debugger actually attaches, thus the v8debug variable is set.

Comment: In both cases, you need to manually attach a debugger. With --debug-brk, it will break execution on the first line of user code, whether a debugger is attached or not.

Answer (score 5):

`process.debugPort` appears to always be present and defaults to 5858. The only way to detect if the program was started explicitly with `--debug` is to check the `process.execArgv` array. `--debug-brk` is pretty obvious to detect: your program won't do anything and you'll get a message about a debugger listening, so that's trivial to figure out. `v8debug` appears to be present when the program is started with `node debug file.js` or when a debugger like node-inspector is currently attached.

Keeping all that in mind, this code will detect whether a debugger (of any kind) is currently attached.

```
 var debug, withDebug;

  debug = false;

  if (typeof v8debug !== "undefined" && v8debug !== null) {
    console.log("v8 debug detected");
    debug = true;
  }

  withDebug = process.execArgv.indexOf('--debug') > -1 || process.execArgv.indexOf('--debug-brk') > -1;

  if (withDebug) {
    console.log("started with debug flag, port: " + process.debugPort);
    debug = true;
  }

  if ((typeof v8debug === "undefined" || v8debug === null) && !withDebug) {
    console.log("neither detected");
  }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `--debug` is actually the really ancient debugger, modern Node.js debugging nowadays is actually done using `--inspect` which allows you to use the Chrome DevTools.

Comment: Right, I wasn't aware of `--inspect` when I wrote this; if I run `node --inspect --debug start.js` is the `--debug` redundant?

Comment: Yeah `--debug` will be removed in [version 8.0.0 of node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/10187), which isn't that far off as we are on 7.4 -- actually latest is 7.5.0 now.
[`node --inspect` was added with 7.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/milestone/15?closed=1), I think, which was 3 months ago.

Comment: By the way - I am using `const isInspected = process.execArgv.includes('--inspect');` in an application at the moment, to disable syntax colouring – so that my devtools console logs aren't overwhelmed with ANSI terminal specific syntax for colours (which don't work in the DevTools console and require different approach).

Comment: be care,  `process.execArgv.includes('--inspect')` will not work for `--inspect=7000` or `--inspect-brk=7000`

Answer (score 2):

There is no v8debug in versions of nodejs >=7.
It seems that the most simple way is to check command line parameters. In debug mode there will be a word 'debug' or 'inspect'

```
const argv = process.execArgv.join();
const isDebug = argv.includes('inspect') || argv.includes('debug');
```

Comment: This answer is completely included in an [earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074641/1269037).

Answer (score 2):

There simple solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889470/how-to-programmatically-detect-debug-mode-in-nodejs/45074641#45074641).

But in general, detect debug mode is not easy - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9617

Comment: This is a combination of (non-)answers, better left as individual comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.defineProperty(global, 'isDebugging', {
    get: function () {
        return typeof v8debug !== 'undefined';
    }
});
```

This works well for webstorm

Comment: Doesn't work if you start the process at the command line with `--debug`.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldnt?

Comment: As pointed out in other answers, v8debug is no longer defined in Node later than v7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, how to check the app to see if it is running on `--inspect`.

I m on nodejs 14, and the solution with the `v8debug` that mentioned above, looks that it does not work any more, for clarity i post the message that i get when i try `--debug`.

`node: [DEP0062]:` node --debug`and`node --debug-brk`are invalid. Please use`node --inspect`and`node --inspect-brk `instead.`

### **Solution**

So how i tackle with this, is to query the `process.execArgv` which is exactly what you need too.

**snipet**:
`const isInspect = process.execArgv.join() === '--inspect'`
`//or ....process.execArgv.toString() === ...`

This `execArgv`, as the docs state:
*The process.execArgv property returns the set of Node.js-specific command-line options passed when the Node.js process was launched. These options do not appear in the array returned by the process.argv property, and do not include the Node.js executable, the name of the script, or any options following the script name. These options are useful in order to spawn child processes with the same execution environment as the parent*.
More in the docs: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/process.html#process_process_execargv