# Getting debug params at runtime

Tags: node.js, debugging

Aside from examining `process.execArgv` and manipulating strings, is there an easier way to determine whether a Node process is listening for debug connections, and if so, in which mode and on what port? Not seeing anything on the [`process`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) API page.

Answer (score 2):

`process` has a `debugPort` property:

```
if (typeof v8debug !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('In debug mode and listening on port: ' + process.debugPort);
}
```

Comment: Oh woah, didn't know about the `v8debug` global. Pretty obscure, ey? Also `process` is a global, too, right? No need to require that? Or should I do that for some reason.

Comment: More on the `v8debug` global found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889470/how-to-programmatically-detect-debug-mode-in-nodejs

Comment: @dimadima of course `process` is a global.  How embarassing... Answer updated.