# Get the time spent waiting on breakpoints in a debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

## Background

Suppose I have a metaphorical patient whose heart beats once per second, and every second, I check whether his last heartbeat was more than five seconds late (and, if so, declare him to be in danger):

```
let lastHeartbeat = Date.now();
// Heartbeater
setInterval(() => lastHeartbeat = Date.now(), 1000);

// Health-checker
setInterval(
    () => {
        if((Date.now() - lastHeartbeat) > 5000){
            alert("Patient has flatlined");
        }
    },
    1000
);
```

## Issue

If I use a debugger to pause the execution of this script at some point, I have a problem: if I remain on a breakpoint for more than five seconds, then, once script execution resumes, my health-checker function is certain to declare that the patient has flatlined.

## Desired behaviour

Instead, I'd like to factor in the time spent in the debugger.

i.e., if I spend twenty seconds sitting on a breakpoint just after an initial heartbeat occurring, and the patient's heart beats again within just one second of releasing that breakpoint, then that patient should *not* be declared as flatlining.

Is there any way to subtract the time spent in the debugger from the health-check condition? e.g.:

```
if((Date.now() - lastHeartbeat - lastTimeSpentInDebugger) > 5000)
```

***Note:*** I'm specifically running the JS in Node.js, rather than in a browser.

Comment: not sure how you would determine lastTimeSpentInDebugger

Comment: [is this relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889470/how-to-programmatically-detect-debug-mode-in-nodejs#13454643) it is 6 years old :/

Comment: @MrPickles This program will *always* be run in debug mode, so the presence of the `v8debug` global variable does not add any useful information (unless it has some properties on it, but I can't find any information that suggests that it does). We need to know *when* the debugger (which listens at all times) is paused on a breakpoint.