# Detect whether Jest code is being debugged

Tags: javascript, jestjs

While stepping over JavaScript code in a test, one can easily exceed the [default timeout of 5 seconds](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api). Jest allows extending that timeout easily:

```js
test('foo', () => {
  // ...
}, 60 * 1000);  // set timeout to one minute
```

Is there a way to detect that Jest is running while debugging, and automatically set that timeout to a very large value? Otherwise, the timeout should be left to the default value.

Jest does set a [`JEST_WORKER_ID` environment variable](https://github.com/facebook/jest/search?q=jest_worker_id), but I haven't found any [official documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=JEST_WORKER_ID+site%3Ajestjs.io) about it.

Comment: This is actually a particular case of [How to programmatically detect debug mode in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889470/how-to-programmatically-detect-debug-mode-in-nodejs).