# What is the best way to automatically set jest timeout when debugging tests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a nodejs project. I'm using the debugger (in IntelliJ if it matters) to step through tests. I'd like to configure my project using best practices so that when I'm using the debugger I modify the test timeout to be longer than the default 5 seconds. I am aware that I can put the following line in package.json to change the timeout.

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "testTimeout": 20000
  }
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to modify the timeout only (and automatically) when debugging. I'm sure there is a good way, but I'm fairly new to nodejs and the conventions/mechanisms  for setting up various envionments.

Comment: But I want the timeout to be different when running the tests normally vs debugging. This is necessary since breakpoints will slow the test execution an arbitrarily large amount.

Comment: You can probably set an env var or something and use that in your config (if it's JS not JSON) but there's no specific handling for this in Jest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using `create-react-app`, the [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) is configured to `src\setupTests.ts`.

This is the entry point before any tests are executed/debugged and if you can detect that you're in a **DEBUG** mode then you can set a new timeout.

e.g.,

```js
if (process.env.DEBUG === 'jest') {
  jest.setTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

In VS Code, you can add `launch.json` configuration as [documented](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/debugging-tests/) with `"DEBUG": "jest"` added to the `env`.

```json
{
  "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-app-rewired",
  "args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--watchAll=false"],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "env": {
    "CI": "true",
    "DEBUG": "jest"
  },
  "disableOptimisticBPs": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you could also try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/debugger-is-attached:

```
import { debuggerIsAttached } from "debugger-is-attached";

// later:
const timeout = await debuggerIsAttached()
   ? 600000 // 10 minutes to debug
   : 5000; // the default 5s for jest
```

*disclaimer: I'm the author*

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple option:

```
if (require('inspector').url()) {
  jest.setTimeout(600_000); // 10 minutes
}
```

The check is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55373190/6813271), which also points to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html) of the native inspector package.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the `launch.json` you could also detect being in debug mode by looking for the `VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS` environment variable.

```js
  if (process.env.VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS) {
    jest.setTimeout(60 * 1000 * 5); // 5 minutes
  }
```

Note: This only works for debugging in VS Code. If your team is using a mix of editors, setting a more generic debug flag is the correct solution.